# Are GAM models linear in the parameters?

Tags: linear-model, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

Consider a GAM model, expressed in `mgcv` just to fix ideas:

```
my_model <- gam(y ~ ti(x1)+ti(x2) + ti(x1, x2), method= "REML")
```

The model is linear in the parameters, right? Each smooth is a linear combination of *basis functions*, which are independent of the data set (unless I use `bs = "ad"`). Thus the model is linear in the parameters, which are the coefficients of the basis functions. Right? And this should be true, whether or not there are interaction terms - it doesn't really matter. The only exception are adaptive smooths, because in that case the coefficients of the basis functions are themselves functions of the covariates (`x1` and `x2`, in my example). Correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, GAMs are linear in the parameters. If we ignore the estimation of smoothness parameters, once we have created the bases for all the covariates we want to fit a smooth effects of, a GAM is just plain old GLM with coefficients for individual basis functions.

This is also true in smooth interactions. The `ti(x1, x2)` term is just a tensor product basis formed by two univariate marginal bases and the resulting coefficients map to individual functions in the 2-d basis. (The `ti()` basis has had the main effects of the separate covariates removed when invoked with two or more covariates.)

Comment: You're a guarantee :-) you should consider collaborating with Simon Wood for the third edition of his book...or write one yourself!

Comment: @DeltaIV Ha! :-) Simon doesn't need any help from me; I'm just a very grateful user myself.